# Json deserialization multiple object

Tags: json, vb.net

I got the problem deserializing the object.

Currently I have two objects that need to be deserialized but I only can input one. How to I achieve that?

Here my code:

```
Public Function PostContract(ByVal data As String) As String Implements IEchoTest.PostContract
    Dim biz As New ContractBiz
    Dim response As New ContractModel.ContractResponse

    Dim request As String = data
    '[Convert to entity data and pass to Business Layer]
    response = biz.CreateContract(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Contract)(request))

    Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response)
End Function
```